# smali grammar files ".g4" for antlr4

Tags: antlr4, smali

The grammar files for smali present here are for antlrv3. I couldnt find any .g4 file for smali. How is this .g4 even created ? Is there a way to convert antlrv3 .g file to one compatible with antlrv4 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is this .g4 even created ?

It is not automatically created: you write it yourself.

> Is there a way to convert antlrv3 .g file to one compatible with antlrv4 ?

No, AFAIK, there is no tool to convert a v3 ANTLR grammar to a v4 version.